# pexpect and ssh connection to ipv6 host

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, ipv6, pexpect

Does pexcpect/pxssh support the SSH connection trough IPv6? 
I've checked in documentation and I haven't seen anything but maybe, I miss something.
If so, what should I do?
If no, could you please advice me what should I do to make my script IPv6 friendly? My code is based on pexpect library.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Paramiko](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/)

its very simple for ssh